# Crear toArray() en Larvel con condiciones if

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Buenas estoy haciendo un filtrado a través de selectores en mi vista y con AJAX consulto a la base de datos para obtener los resultados, pero necesito tener un array solo con los campos seleccionados.

**Mi query**

```
$vendida = Tecnologia::selectRaw('name, COUNT(tecnologia_id) AS Total')
            ->rightJoin('equipos', 'tecnologias.id', '=', 'equipos.tecnologia_id')
            ->groupBy('name')
            ->whereYear('equipos.fecha_adquirido', '=', $request->ano2)
            ->get()
            ->toArray();

return compact('vendida');
```

**Resultado, que luego implanto en una gráfica charts.js**

```
array:16 [
  0 => array:2 [
    "name" => "Equipo1"
    "Total" => 10
  ]
  1 => array:2 [
    "name" => "Equipo2"
    "Total" => 5
  ]
  2 => array:2 [
    "name" => "Equipo3"
    "Total" => 1
  ]
  3 => array:2 [
    "name" => "Equipo4"
    "Total" => 9
  ]
  4 => array:2 [
    "name" => "Equipo5"
    "Total" => 5
  ]
]
```

Pero ahora tengo un selector que puede venir vacio o bien con un resultado para filtrar,

```
$vendida = Tecnologia::selectRaw('name, COUNT(tecnologia_id) AS Total')
            ->rightJoin('equipos', 'tecnologias.id', '=', 'equipos.tecnologia_id')
            ->groupBy('name')
            ->whereYear('equipos.fecha_adquirido', '=', $request->ano2)
            ->get();
 
            if(!empty($request->tipo))
            {
                $vendida->$vendida->where('equipos.estado', $request->tipo);
            }
            
            $vendida->toArray();
        return compact('vendida');
```

Estoy probando así, pero al querer devolver un array no obtengo bien los datos, que es lo que estoy haciendo mal?

---

Bien lo he solucionado así pero no se muy bien entender por que si funciona así.

```
$vendida = Tecnologia::selectRaw('name, COUNT(tecnologia_id) AS Total')
            ->rightJoin('equipos', 'tecnologias.id', '=', 'equipos.tecnologia_id')
            ->groupBy('name')
            ->whereYear('equipos.fecha_adquirido', '=', $request->ano2);
            
 
            if(!empty($request->tipo))
            {
                $vendida->where('equipos.estado', $request->tipo);
            }

            if(!empty($request->mes2))
            {
                $vendida->whereMonth('equipos.fecha_adquirido', $request->mes2);
            }

            $vendida = $vendida->get();
            $vendida = $vendida->toArray();

        return compact('vendida');
```

Comment: Cuando no te funcionaba es por que mandabas llamar a la función `get()` y cierras la consulta; por ello no podías aplicar mas where